# How to change a message in a Modal by using the JQuery empty() method?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I created a form where the user is asked to fill several fields (name, surname, email, phone number and comments).

I have the function *validateForm* * with an else if statement: if all fields are filled correctly it will activate a Modal which displays a "message 1" ("Are you sure that you want to send you info?"). Otherwise, it will display a specific message (message 2,3,4 or 5) which differs according to which field is left empty (i.e.: if the field "name" is filled correctly the modal will display "please insert your surname"; if both fields are filled the modal will display "please insert your email"; and so on...).

Instead than using a modal for each field I want to be filled out, I prefer to use a modal, associate an ID to it and exploit the JQuery `.empty()` method to overwrite the text of the original content of the modal with the specific text for each event (event 1: field of name empty; event 2: field of surname empty, and so on...).

I wrote the following function:

```
function validateForm(){    
console.log("test validateForm");
if ($('#name').val()=="") {
      $("#testoMyModal").html("Inserisci il nome");
    } else if ($('#surname').val()=="") {
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il cognome");
    } else if ($('#email').val()=="") {
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci l'indirizzo eMail");
    } else if ($('#numero').val()=="") {
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il numero di telefono");
    } else if ($('#commenti').val()=="") {
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il testo della richiesta");
    } else {
        $('#myModal2').modal('show');
    }
}
```

It runs correctly because the console doesn't report errors and the value of the console.log() is displayed correctly. But it doesn't do the job, that's to say it doesn't perform the desired task and no messages are displayed.

I wonder if I wrote the ID associated to the modal in the wrong place inside it? My html code is the following (I copy/paste the snippit related to the two modals only):

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal"> 
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="testoMyModal" class="modal-body">
        <p>Si prega di controllare che tutti i campi siano stati compilati correttamente</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- fine finestra modale di Bootstrap -->

<!-- aggiungo una seconda modale per chiedere conferma della scelta-->

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sei sicuro di voler inviare i dati?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Indetro</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Invia</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my question:

How to change a message in a **Modal** by using the **jQuery `.empty()` method** (which relates to it by associating to its ID) ?

- - - - - [S O L V E D] - - - - - - - - - >

I solved the problem by adding an instruction with the Bootstrap `.modal("show")` method for every text field the user has to fill out. The previous instructions were correct but the function needed to specify to show the modal window.

The correct snippet is the following:

```
function validateForm(){    
console.log('function "validateForm" has been activated');  
if ($('#name').val()=="") {
      console.log('validate name');
      $("#testoMyModal").html("Inserisci il nome");
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else if ($('#cognome').val()=="") {
      console.log('validate surname');
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il cognome");
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else if ($('#email').val()=="") {
      console.log('validate email address');
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci l'indirizzo eMail");
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else if ($('#numero').val()=="") {
      console.log('validate number');
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il numero di telefono");
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else if ($('#commenti').val()=="") {
      console.log('validate text Area');
      $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il testo della richiesta");
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else {
        $('#myModal2').modal('show');
        console.log('all fields are filled :)');
    }
}
```

Now the modal window is displayed correctly whenever a text field is left empty.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how `if/else` work.  If any of the `if` or `else if` conditionals are true, the final `else` will never execute.  You need to perform the show if any of the if or else if are true.

Comment: hi @gibberish, thank you for your comment, I edited my question by specifying the code which runs correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function validateForm() {
  var showModal = true;

  if ($('#name').val() == "") {
    $("#testoMyModal").html("Inserisci il nome");
  } else if ($('#surname').val() == "") {
    $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il cognome");
  } else if ($('#email').val() == "") {
    $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci l'indirizzo eMail");
  } else if ($('#numero').val() == "") {
    $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il numero di telefono");
  } else if ($('#commenti').val() == "") {
    $('#testoMyModal').html("Inserisci il testo della richiesta");
  } else {
    showModal = false;
  }

  if (showModal) $('#myModal2').modal('show');
}
```

You need to show the modal if any of the if or else if conditions are true.  The `else` condition only happens if all the previous conditions are not true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wrote a different code but your suggestion definitely helped me to focus on the problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the `.empty()` method even - if you just use `.html()` it will overwrite what was there previously, without even using `.empty()`

```
$('[id^=btn_]').click(function(){
    var buttNum = this.id.split('_')[1];
    var content = $('#mdl'+buttNum).html();
    $('#myModal1 .modal-body').html(content);
});
```

#### DEMO:

```js
$('[id^=btn_]').click(function(){
  var buttNum = this.id.split('_')[1];
  //alert(buttNum);
  var content = $('#mdl'+buttNum).html();
  $('#myModal1 .modal-body').html(content);
});
```

```css
#mdl1, #mdl2, #mdl3{display:none;} /*  Hide the divs containing modal content */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Re-Using the Same Modal</h3>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button id="btn_1" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal One</button>
  <button id="btn_2" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal Two</button>
  <button id="btn_3" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Ogden Nash Poem</button>

  <!-- Re-Usable Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Stick your modal content in hidden divs at bottom of the page -->
  <div id="mdl1">
    <div>Best Viewed Full-Screen -- Click outside modal to close modal</div>
    <form name="getinfo" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="php/gmail.php" method="POST">
      <div class="form-style-8">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <label for="msg">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Username:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="user" name="username">

      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Password:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="password">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Confirm Password:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="cpassword">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">3 Hashtags:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="tags" name="hashtags">   
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="mdl2">
      <div>Click outside modal to close modal</div>
      <h1>Image of an Animal</h1>
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/animals" />
  </div><!-- #mdl2 -->
  <div id="mdl3">
      <div>Click outside modal to close modal</div>
      <h1>Poem by Ogden Nash</h1>
      <div style="font-size:1.4rem;">
  <div>The hands of the clock were reaching high</div>
  <div>In an old midtown hotel;</div>
  <div>I name no name, but its sordid fame</div>
  <div>Is table talk in hell.</div>
  <div>I name no name, but hell's own flame</div>
  <div>Illumes the lobby garish,</div>
  <div>A gilded snare just off Times Square</div>
  <div>For the maidens of the parish.</div>

  <div>The revolving door swept the grimy floor</div>
  <div>Like a crinoline grotesque,</div>
  <div>And a lowly bum from an ancient slum</div>
  <div>Crept furtively past the desk.</div>
  <div>His footsteps sift into the lift</div>
  <div>As a knife in the sheath is slipped,</div>
  <div>Stealthy and swift into the lift</div>
  <div>As a vampire into a crypt.</div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- #mdl3 -->
</body>
</html>
```